# Poetry config - command: poetry not found, but path added to bashrc and shrc files. export path command caused directory error running script

Tags: python-poetry

I am a new linux/python user trying to get poetry set up. Basically I can make the poetry command work by using the export path statement, but that only causes a directory issue when executing script. Ive downloaded poetry using the command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
```

I know that it's installed because if I try and run that again, it says it already downloaded. I run into the error:

```
command: poetry not found
```

I used

```
nano ./bashrc
nano ./shrc
```

in terminal and I've edited both of those with

```
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

then, I'm following instructions to run a set of scripts under directory "thermalproc" that I've been given, and the path is `~/Desktop/VideoProcessing/thermalproc-20220625/thermalproc` . I'm to use the command

```
poetry run thermalproc
```

the only thing that I have done to make the command work is to use that export line directly in the terminal, and that does allow the command to work, but if i run just the command as so:

```
 joshua@Andrea-G750JZA:~$ poetry run thermalproc
```

it returns

```
  RuntimeError

  Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /home/joshua or its parents

  at .poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/poetry/core/factory.py:369 in locate
      365│             if poetry_file.exists():
      366│                 return poetry_file
      367│ 
      368│         else:
    → 369│             raise RuntimeError(
      370│                 "Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in {} or its parents".format(
      371│                     cwd
      372│                 )
      373│             )
```

and if I run in the directory of the script as I originally thought I should:

```
joshua@Andrea-G750JZA:~/Desktop/VideoProcessing/thermalproc-20220625/thermalproc$ poetry run thermalproc.

  FileNotFoundError

  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/snap/bin/thermalproc.'

  at /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py:601 in _execvpe
       597│         path_list = map(fsencode, path_list)
       598│     for dir in path_list:
       599│         fullname = path.join(dir, file)
       600│         try:
    →  601│             exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
       602│         except (FileNotFoundError, NotADirectoryError) as e:
       603│             last_exc = e
       604│         except OSError as e:
       605│             last_exc = e
```

Thanks for sticking it out this long, any advice would be greatly appreciated!